# Can I assign value from the same array of objects? REACT - NATIVE

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have an array of objects, and each of those objects have an icon, I want to know if it's possible to assign the property color of the icon the same as the property color of the object, let me show you:

```
Icon_config =[
  {name: "home", color: "red", icon: <Entypo name = "home" size = {30} color = {Icon_config[0].color}/>},
  {object 2},
  {object 3},
```

As you can see its an array of objects, I want the property color of the icon be the same as the property color of the object, I tried it with:

```
 Icon_config[0].color
```

But it gives me error, thanks :)

Comment: What error does it give?

Comment: It will give error because icon prop is requesting a value which is not initialised yet. Why you need this setup?